# How to get current simulation time in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I am measuring energy level when the packet comes to one of the specific LCN from anothers.I want to get the current simulation time when packet arrives to this LCN.To do this, I used

```
SimTime();
```

function but it always gives me the 0. So, how can I get current simulation time. I need to draw the energy level of the LCN with respect to time until simulation ends.I mean what is energy level of of LCN when the time is 10? (for example)

Comment: have you tried using `simTime()` instead of `SimTime()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `SimTime()` you actually call the constructor for the class [`SimTime`](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classSimTime.html).

What you are looking for is the global function `simTime()`.